# SurfaceView image taken different than shown

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, android-camera

I created a layout where my surface view has been resized from the "original size", I did the following:

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    int mPixels=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.profile_pic_dimension); //200
    params.width=mPixels;
    params.height=mPixels;
    mSurfaceView.setLayoutParams(params);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

and I obtain a view like this:
http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/9379/layoutp.png

but then.. whenever I take the picture.. it doesn't saves as how I can see it on the view... but instead it saves it normal size like if the view was taking the whole screen (like if the surfaceview was never resized).

I tried using this:

```
Camera.ShutterCallback mShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters(); 
                p.setPictureSize(mSurfaceView.getWidth(), mSurfaceView.getHeight()); 
               mCamera.setParameters(p); 
        }
    };
```

but still didn't get the image size i wanted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just supply any width and height value when setting the picture (or preview) size. In stead, you'll have to use one of the items from the list of supported sizes, which you can retrieve by calling [`getSupportedPictureSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29) (there's an equivalent for the preview).

So far I haven't come across any devices that support taking square pictures, so after a 4:3, 16:9, 16:10, or whatever ratio, picture has been taken, you will have to 'cut' out the relevant part yourself, and optionally scale it down to a specific dimension. Probably the most straightforward way to do this, is by creating a [new Bitmap as a subset from a source Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) (and then optionally scale it down). In order to get the source bitmap, you'll likely need to hook up a `PictureCallback` to the camera with [`takePicture(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29).

Comment: Dear @MH. I couldn't find a way to determine the redundant part of image that is not shown on the preview but its on the taken image. For example the preview size is 720*480 and the image size is 3264*2448, so how can I determine the extra part that is not shown on the preview then cut it out form the taken image?

Comment: @Behzad: If you know the preview size and final image size, then you should be able to calculate the invisible area with some basic math (hint: you'll need to calculate the aspect ratio of the preview size). The only variable in the equation is the 'gravity' of the visible area. For example, with a 'center' gravity, you'll want to crop an equal amount of invisible pixels from, say, the top and bottom (as opposed to cropping them all from on side). If this sounds complicated, just draw two differently sized rectangles on a piece of paper and work out a specific example. :)

Comment: thanks, but how can I calculate the aspect ratio? that's the question

Comment: @Behzad: The aspect ratio is nothing more than the width divided by the height, or vice versa...

Comment: Have u done this? If you got the solution, will u please share